# Firestore setDoc getting FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using both Firebase auth and Firestore to store user information. I want to be able to store the users information under a document of the same id as the uid autogenerated when they create an account using the auth. My issue is that when I try to write the data to the firestore db it fails to complete.

here is the code for the initialization and where it is called.

```
// The firebase.js file
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export default app;
export const db = getFirestore(app);


// Where the user will select a username to be tied to their account
import React, { useState} from "react";
import db from "../firebase"
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"
import {Form, Button, Card, Alert, Container} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "../components/Header"
import Footer from "../components/Footer"

export default function FinishSignup() {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth()
    const [error, setError] = useState('')
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
    const navigate = useNavigate("/")
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const uid = currentUser.uid
        const email = currentUser.email

        try {
            setLoading(true)
            setError("")
            console.log(uid)
            console.log(email)
            console.log(username)
            await setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid), {
                username: username, 
                email: email
            })
            navigate("/")
        } catch (error){
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error)
            setError("Failed to complete signup")
        }

        setLoading(false)
    }

    return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#0b1321ff" }}>
            <Header />
            <Container className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                style={{ minHeight: "100vh", backgroundColor: "#0b1321ff", color: '#b7c1d3ff' }}
            >
                <div className="w-100" style={{ maxWidth: '400px' }}>
                    <Card style={{ backgroundColor: "#0b1321ff", color: '#b7c1d3ff', border: '3px ridge #b7c1d3ff' }}>
                        <Card.Body>
                            <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Finish Setting Up Your Account</h2>
                            {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
                            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <Form.Group id="username">
                                    <Form.Label>Username</Form.Label>
                                    <Form.Control type="text" onChange={(e) => {setUsername(e.target.value)}} />
                                </Form.Group>
                                <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100 text-center mt-2" type="submit"
                                    style={{backgroundColor: '#0b1321ff', color: '#67a170ff', border: '2px ridge #67a170ff'}}>Finish Signup</Button>
                            </Form>
                        </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                </div>
            </Container>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've looked over all the related questions I could find but they all had different problems or their solutions didn't work for my code. What is happening so far is that everything logs out to be what i'd expect and is a string, but the actual `setDoc` function fails and the catch statement kicks in before `navigate` function goes and when I check the database it is registering reads but not writes in addition to no new documents being created.

Comment: Could you share what's the exact error? Perhaps update your catch block as follows `catch (error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
    setError("Failed to complete signup");
}`

Comment: Sure thing. @hersh that spits out:  Error adding document:  FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Comment: thanks for that! You look to be using the compat version which might point to the issue, which firebase version are you using?

Comment: @hersh I am currently using version 9.8.1

Comment: I tried switching my firebase import to `import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"` and adjusting the rest to work with that but the entire app just renders as a white screen when I do so.

Comment: Check the console for the error, if there's an error, please share

Comment: I fixed the blank screen error and implemented all suggested changes here and in your answer and updated to reflect so above. I am still getting the same error `FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is likely due to the inconsistent use firebase APIs, with version 9.8.1 [you should be using the Modular API instead of compat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

You can update your firebase initialization as follows to use the Modular API

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    // your config
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Comment: I implemented these changes and got the same error. I updated my question to reflect my changes. Any ideas?

Comment: While this didn't get me all the way to the solution you got me mostly there. Thank you for your help. I managed to solve the question and put my solution below. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So for you having trouble with Firestore not writing the data as expected. There are 2 suggestions which according to me would make things work

1. Make sure your Firestore database rules allow write operations for authenticated users.

   ```
   rules_version = '2';
   service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{userId} {
           allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
           }
        }
   }
   ```

This would typically allow read and write operations on a user document if the user is authenticated and the `userId` matches the `uid` of the authenticated user.

2.Error Handling: It would be helpful to log the error in your catch block to understand what’s going wrong.

```
catch (error) {
  console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  setError("Failed to complete signup");
}
```

Comment: I currently have the rules allowing writing to the document in this scenario. I have implemented the error catching code you suggested and provided the error above.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a few things and found a solution that works. Rather than import db from the `firebase.js` file like so: `export const db = getFirestore(app);` then importing it in the desired file like so: `import db from "../firebase"` as I have been doing. it works best to `import app from "../firebase"` and `import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"` at the top of the component that will be using the database and define db in that file as such: `const db = getFirestore(app)`. For whatever reason doing it differently produces the above error